# How do I convert a numeric column into datetime without timezone in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, alter-column

I want to alter the table to change the datatype of a column from numeric into timestamp without timezone. It has existing data. Are there gotchas I need to watch out for?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE <table name>
ALTER COLUMN <column name> type timestamp without time zone
USING to_timestamp(<column name>) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE test.numericdates
ALTER COLUMN date type timestamp without time zone
USING to_timestamp(date) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```